# Logrotate copytruncate option taking too much time

Tags: bash, shell-script, file-copy, logrotate

I am running logrotate every 4 hours using crontab. 
I want to rotate files at every 50G which is expected in 4 hours. 
My **logrotate.config** is like below :

```
/log/*/*/*/*.log
{
        size 50G
        copytruncate
        missingok
        notifempty
        nocompress
        postrotate
                dir=${1%/*}
                mv "$1" "$dir"\/"$(basename $1 .1)-$(date +'%Y%m%d_%H%M').1";
        endscript
        lastaction
                find /log -type f -name "*.1" -exec bash -c 'gzip -nc "$1" > "${1:0:-2}.gz"; rm "$1"' _ {} \;
        endscript
}
```

But my files are in GBs. So is it ok to use copytruncate option ? or there is any other alternative to it. 
One solution I can think of is, using prerotate script to rename the file rather than copying.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense attacking the origin of those logs?  Is there anything you need inside?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille can you elaborate?

Comment: Can't you reduce the amount of logging to something reasonable?  Perhaps the application creating the logs is running in debug mode?

Comment: No. I can't reduce the logs. can you suggest some method to optimize the rotation and compression process?

Comment: Can you tell your application it needs to re-open the logs?

Comment: No. My application is only dumping the logs. Not reading back. I am using that for another purpose.

Comment: In that case I would remove copytruncate, nocompress and postrotate and lastaction scripts.  After rotation, see if your application dumps to new logs.

Answer (score 1):

1) your log files are TOO large. add a logrotate entry to your crontab (every 5 minutes or so) to make them smaller and easier to handle.
2) copytruncate will copy (50GB is a lot), then truncate (ftruncate) the file to 0 bytes. this takes time and you will lose records while performing this.
3) try to parse the file and get rid of the unnecessary info (like field description - create a header) and keep the values only, comma (or other mark) separated.

best options:
 - higher frequency.
 - no copytruncate.
 - kill -HUP the process to reread the conf file.
 - rotate 1.
 - compress.
 - move the gzipped log file to a safe location